# Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined

Tags: exm

I am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2 and EXM 3.4 Update 1. I have created Regular email campaign. After creating this campaign page, it displays blank page without any information. When I looked at console for any error, it is showing below exception:

> sitecore-1.0.2.js:855 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'initialize' of undefined
>       at child.addBehavior (sitecore-1.0.2.js:855)
>       at sitecore-1.0.2.js:605
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (underscore.1.4.4.js:78)
>       at child.views.View (sitecore-1.0.2.js:604)
>       at child [as constructor] (sitecore-1.0.2.js:209)
>       at child [as constructor] (sitecore-1.0.2.js:209)
>       at new child (sitecore-1.0.2.js:209)
>       at exposedComponent (sitecore-1.0.2.js:2570)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (sitecore-1.0.2.js:2683)

[image]

Comment: Is this a clean installation of Sitecore + EXM?

Comment: Could you provide your Sitecore log file (if you have any errors there)?

Comment: @JacobNielsen Yes it has fresh installation

Comment: I just installed core package from some working environment, now it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error posted suggests that SPEAK is not able to render the page correctly.

The EXM UI is a SPEAK application driven by item configuration in the Sitecore Core Database. While it is rare that someone would need to customize or change the EXM UI in the Core Database, it's not unusual.

Additionally, in the event of either a failed upgrade or misaligned core database, it's possible that items were missing, causing SPEAK to fail, causing this initialize error.

The EXM Application path in the Core Database is `/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM` and has a folder structure that looks similar to this:

[image]